# Comparing Character from Character-Array to Character constants

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, logical-operators

I have a problem with the following code. My idea is to check for invalid Characters in my String before I go on with it. But somehow my involvesInvalidChar- method always returns true, even though it shouldn't. The String consists only of four specific uppercase-letters. Im checking if there are others involved.

```
public static int method (String someString) {

  // array of characters from String    
  char[] charArray = someString.toCharArray();

  // are there invalid characters in the Array?
  if (involvesInvalidChars(charArray)) {
            return -1;
  }
... // code following 
}

private static boolean involvesInvalidChars (char[] charArray) {

  // for each char in the array     
  for (char ch : arrayOfChars) {

    // check for invalid chars
    if ((ch != 'A') || (ch != 'C') || ...) {

        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(ch != 'A') || (ch != 'C')` is always true indeed (there is no `char` that is A AND C).

Change `||` to `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
if ((ch != 'A') || (ch != 'C') || ...) {
```

should be

```
if ((ch != 'A') && (ch != 'C') && ...) {
```

Because you want the invalid character to **not** be **any** of characters, not just **one** character.

2) There's an easier way to do this, for uppercase alphabets, try this:

```
for(char ch: arrayOfChars)
    if((int)ch < 65 || (int) ch > 90)
        return false;
```

Here we are comparing ASCII codes instead of each character separately, which is more efficient in writing and otherwise. You can also add lowercase charaters and such into this range.

Answer (score 0):

You should change invalid chars check to:

```
// check for invalid chars
if ((ch != 'A') && (ch != 'C') && ...) {

    return true;
}
```

Your current condition always return true

Answer (score 0):

You are applying a buggy method to solve your problem -

1. You should not use short-circuit or operator(||) between condition checks.It is always returning true.You should be using &&
2. You should use regex to solve your problem

   private static boolean involvesInvalidChars (String string)

   {
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[ABCD]");

   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
   return matcher.find();

   }